# How can I apply a CGAffineTransform to a UICollectionViewCell while the UICollectionView is scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I am creating a kind of horizontally scrolling menu with multiple items that the user can scroll through.(see picture at the bottom for a preview of what I mean)

The UICollectionView offset already always centers on one of its items. What I want to do is that when an item is the next one to approach the center, I want to apply a transformation to make it larger. This is the code that I'm using to achieve this (the logic doesn't handle animating out of the center or scrolling the other direction yet):

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        guard let scrolledCollectionView = scrollView as? UICollectionView,
            let flowLayout = scrolledCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else { return }

        let itemWidth = flowLayout.itemSize.width

        let collectionViewCenter = collectionView.bounds.width * 0.5 + scrolledCollectionView.contentOffset.x

        let itemToEnlarge = Int((scrolledCollectionView.contentOffset.x + (itemWidth * 0.5)) / (itemWidth + flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing))

        let itemEnlargeIndexpath = IndexPath(row: itemToEnlarge, section: 0)

        guard let cellToAnimate = collectionView.cellForItem(at: itemEnlargeIndexpath) else { return }

        let diff = cellToAnimate.center.x - collectionViewCenter

        var transformationVolume: CGFloat = 1

        if diff == 0 {
            transformationVolume += 0.2
        } else {
            transformationVolume += (0.2 / diff)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cellToAnimate.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: transformationVolume, y: transformationVolume)
        }
    }
```

The problem that I'm having is that the transformation is only applied once the collectionview has stopped scrolling. Does anyone know if there's a way to apply the transformation dynamically? So that if you scroll the item towards the center little by little, the transformation is applied incrementally.

[image]